# Button clicked event not triggering after lost focus event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms c# form with some comboBoxes ,  cancel and save  buttons that work fine.
I now need to capture when the user has finished entering text into a comboBox.
I add an empty ( for now)  lostFocus (or Leave) event to the combbox ,  which triggers fine. However if the cause of that event was a cancel or save button press , the corresponding event is no longer triggered. These buttons still work fine if pressed at other times.

Should these two event be firing in sequence or is there some better way to capture completed text entry?

Comment: I say, I have $1 trillion and, everyone will believe me! no?...then share the code dear, show the asset that you've!!

Comment: This should work just fine - please provide the code of your form.

Comment: The form has 700 lines of code I can't post them all here and if just post some I will probably miss the bit that is causing the problem.  Is there a way of debugging the event process?

Comment: One simple workaround would be to add the call from the leave to the click of the two special buttons as well (making sure it gets called only once)..

Comment: If you just post some code (the Cancel and Save click events would be particularly helpful) it would go a long way toward someone trying to help you. If you've got 700 lines in there, you need to do some extraction and refactoring...

Answer (score 0):

The `Leave` and/or `LoseFocus` events do not get triggered because you do not leave the combobox and because it doesn't lose focus when you press `Enter` or `Escape`.

Therefore the best way is to add the function you are triggering in the `LoseFocus` event, also to the `Button` click events of the `Cancel-` and the `Accept-Buttons`.

Adding a call to the leave event itself: `comboBox1.Leave(null, null);` would be the simplest way.

To make sure that the function is called only once, I check who has focus in the `ButtonClick` events:

```
private void acceptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.ContainsFocus) comboBox1_Leave(acceptButton, null);
    // do accept stuff here..
}

private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.ContainsFocus) comboBox1_Leave(cancelButton, null);
    // do cancel stuff here..
}

private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do leave stuff here..
    Console.WriteLine(sender);
}
```

I also pass in the `Button` so you could check the `sender` to see how the `Leave` was triggered..

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question here as I feel it might be useful to other newbies.

The breakpoint I had set in my empty  lostFocus event was stopping button click event from occurring. When I removed the breakpoint the problem went away.

However when I added code to my lostFocus event, a form redraw was sometimes moving the buttons and preventing their events from firing. To solve this problem I adapted TaWs very useful answer and fired the button event from within the lostFocus event.

```
private void comboBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool saving = btnSave.ContainsFocus;

    // form redraw stuff here..
    if (saving)
         btnSave_Click(btnSave, null);
}
```